# Bartender Printing in A4

Tags: bartender

Is it Possible to print using bartender in different location?

i have A4 size label and has a 6 column and 2 row each.

here is my database field

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBiMK.png)

and here is my sample template

[Bartender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCAiv.png)

Comment: What do you mean with a different location?

Comment: i have 6 column and 2 row. and i will specified on where to print. for example iwant to print in 5 column 1st row. or 1 column second row. look at my posted picture

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to print multiple records on one page if you want to select the location for each record on one page. There are a few ways to create a template where you can freely select the location on a A4 paper but this will work for one record per page. Please comment if one record is fine and I will create a small guide to set it up.